# Namespace and clases nesting issue

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to encapsulate a sprite based game and I have having trouble accesing classes withing the same namespace.
Here is the code for the namespace:

```
namespace Client
{
    public class Bomb : public Entity
    {
    private:
        int tiempo;
        TipoBomba tipo;
    public:
        Bomb(int px, int py, int tiempo, TipoBomba tipo);
        int getX();
        int getY();
        int getTiempo();
        void setTiempo(int t);
        Client::TipoBomba getTipo();
        void reducirTiempo();
        void Mostrar(Graphics ^ gr);
        void explotar(Graphics ^ gr);
    };
    public class Game
    {
        int nivel;
        LivingEntity* objJugador;
        //Enemigo* objEnemigo;
    public:
        ~Game(void);
        Game(void);
        static int ** matriz;
        static std::vector<Bomb*> bombas;
        static bool isBloque(int px, int py);
        static bool isVacio(int px, int py);
        static void romperBloque(int px, int py, Graphics^ gr);
        static bool isRompible(int px, int py);
        static bool isBomba(int px, int py);
        Point getPrimeraPosicionJugador();
        static void addBomba(Bomb* b);
        static void cargarMatriz();
        void setDireccion_Jugador(Direccion dir);
        void Crear_Enemigo(int px, int py);
        void Crear_Jugador(int px, int py);
        void Mover_Entidades(Graphics^ gr);
        Client::Player* getJugador();
        int getNivel();
        void setNivel(int n);
    };
    public class Player : public LivingEntity
    {
        int vidas;
        int bombas;
    public:
        Player(void);
        Player(int px, int py);
        void Mostrar(Graphics^ gr);
        void Mover(Graphics^ gr);
        int getVidas();
        int getBombas();
        void setBombas(int bombas);
        void setVidas(int vidas);
    };
    public class Enemy : public LivingEntity
    {
    public:
        ~Enemy(void);
        Enemy(void);
        Enemy(int px, int py);
        void Mover(Graphics^ gr);
        void Mostrar(Graphics^ gr);
    };
    public enum TipoBomba
    {
        BASICA,
        GRANDE
    };
}
```

The warnings are:

- `Warning  60  warning C4183: 'getJugador': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'`
- `Warning  37  warning C4183: 'getTipo': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'`

And the errors are:

- `Error    6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`
- `Error    10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

I tried changing from Client::Player to just Player (same with TipoBomba) and it didn't work. I also tried putting public before classes and still the same. Is there any kind of keyword I need to use or is it just namespace semantics?.Thanks

EDIT:

Everything worked, whoever now I am getting a lot of LINKER errors when compiling. Examples:

```
Error   10  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   26  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   42  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   58  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   2   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   18  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   34  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   50  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0Entity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   13  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   29  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   45  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   61  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@$$FQAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   5   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   21  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   37  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   53  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall LivingEntity::LivingEntity(int,int,char *,int,int)" (??0LivingEntity@@QAE@HHPADHH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   14  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   30  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   46  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   62  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   6   error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   22  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   38  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   54  error LNK2005: "public: enum Direccion __thiscall LivingEntity::getMovimiento(void)" (?getMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAE?AW4Direccion@@XZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   11  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   27  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   43  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   59  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   3   error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   19  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   35  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   51  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getX(void)" (?getX@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   12  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   28  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   44  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   60  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@$$FQAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   4   error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   20  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   36  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   52  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Entity::getY(void)" (?getY@Entity@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bomb.obj   C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   15  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   31  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   47  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   63  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   7   error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   23  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   39  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   55  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDx(int)" (?setDx@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   16  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   32  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   48  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   64  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   8   error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   24  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   40  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   56  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setDy(int)" (?setDy@LivingEntity@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj    C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   17  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   33  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   49  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   65  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@$$FQAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   9   error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Enemy.obj   BombermanUPC
Error   25  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   41  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   57  error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall LivingEntity::setMovimiento(enum Direccion)" (?setMovimiento@LivingEntity@@QAEXW4Direccion@@@Z) already defined in Bomb.obj C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Player.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   69  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Client::Bomb::getX(void)" (?getX@Bomb@Client@@$$FQAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl Client::Game::isBomba(int,int)" (?isBomba@Game@Client@@$$FSA_NHH@Z)  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   70  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Client::Bomb::getY(void)" (?getY@Bomb@Client@@$$FQAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl Client::Game::isBomba(int,int)" (?isBomba@Game@Client@@$$FSA_NHH@Z)  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   71  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Client::Game::addBomba(class Client::Bomb *)" (?addBomba@Game@Client@@$$FSAXPAVBomb@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall BombermanUPC::MyForm::Key_Press(class System::Object ^,class System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs ^)" (?Key_Press@MyForm@BombermanUPC@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVKeyEventArgs@Forms@Windows@4@@Z)  C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   68  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000107) "public: static void __cdecl Client::Game::addBomba(class Client::Bomb *)" (?addBomba@Game@Client@@$$FSAXPAVBomb@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall BombermanUPC::MyForm::Key_Press(class System::Object ^,class System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs ^)" (?Key_Press@MyForm@BombermanUPC@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVKeyEventArgs@Forms@Windows@4@@Z) C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\MyForm.obj  BombermanUPC
Error   66  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00047F) "public: int __thiscall Client::Bomb::getX(void)" (?getX@Bomb@Client@@$$FQAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl Client::Game::isBomba(int,int)" (?isBomba@Game@Client@@$$FSA_NHH@Z) C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
Error   67  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000480) "public: int __thiscall Client::Bomb::getY(void)" (?getY@Bomb@Client@@$$FQAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl Client::Game::isBomba(int,int)" (?isBomba@Game@Client@@$$FSA_NHH@Z) C:\Users\Martin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BombermanUPC\BombermanUPC\Game.obj    BombermanUPC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ compiler evaluates things line-by-line. (That's an oversimplification, but close enough for this discussion.) When it gets to the line that declares `getJugador`, it knows nothing about the `Client::Player` type, because it hasn't gotten there yet!

There's a couple ways to fix this:

- You can add forward declarations of your classes. `public class Player : public LivingEntity;` tells the compiler "there is a class named Player, which I will declare the contents of later".
- You can re-arrange your class definitions so that they're in order. Any reference to another type is to a type earlier in the file.
- (Recommended) Separate your classes into their own header files. `#include` any other class definitions needed. As long as you don't have any circular references, this will take care of it.

Other things:

- Since you have parameters of type `Graphics^`, it's obvious that you are using C++/CLI here. Given that, I highly *highly* recommend that you make your classes managed ones. Define the classes as `public ref class`, and always declare variables and parameters as `MyClass^`.
- In general, when writing C++/CLI, I recommend doing things in the manner of the higher-level language, i.e., C#. So managed classes like I said, and use the .Net library rather than the C++ one.

Comment: I am using that structure to avoid circular includes. Also using unmanaged classes to make sure I am the one who controls the memore and the deleting of the instances.

Comment: I did as told  , whoever now I am getting a lot of Linker errors when comiling.

Comment: You need to put the declaration of your methods in the header files, and the implementation of the methods in .cpp files.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I got a 2DVector in the Game class. I want to have a static class have methods wich can read the vector and return a value on xxx conditions. However if I separe the class in different files I would have the circular includes. Because said class would include Game, and Game would include Bomb, and bomb includes said class (Utility).

Comment: Do the classes refer to each other in their *definitions* (method parameters & return values), or in their *implementations* (local variables within a method only)? If it's the latter, then just putting the method contents into .cpp files will take care of it, just #include the minimum necessary from the .h file, and the rest from the .cpp file. If the former, then use a forward declaration instead of a #include in the header files, and do the full include within the .cpp files.

Comment: Visual Studio is not giving me any errors right now. Rather when I do compile the program I get those linker errors I posted.

Comment: Those multiple definition errors are because you have your method implementations in your header files, or other files that you're #including and are therefore being compiled multiple times. (Either that, or you got enthusiastic with your copy-paste when it should be cut-paste.) Make sure that each method is only implemented once, in a file that is only compiled once.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.